# scanf() is scanning a character before it should even be initialized

Tags: c, scanf

Can some body explain to me why `card_T2` is scanning even before `printf("Type in flop card 2: \n");` is shown on the screen?

```c
char card_T1[2];
char card_T2[2];

printf("Type in flop card 1: \n");

scanf("%c",&card_T1[0]);    //Card value
scanf("%c",&card_T1[1]);    //Card categorie

printf("%c\n",card_T1[0]);
printf("%c",card_T1[1]);

printf("Type in flop card 2: \n");

scanf("%c",&card_T2[0]);    //Card value
scanf("%c",&card_T2[1]);    //Card categorie
    
printf("%c\n",card_T2[0]);
printf("%c",card_T2[1]);

return 0;
```

I want the first `scanf` to scan something like "2k", But if i press enter after typing it, the enter is then scanned on to `card_T2[0]`. I don't understand why.

Also if I type in something like "456" then press enter, `card_T1[0] = 4`, `card_T1[1] = 5`, `card_T2[0] = 6` and `card_T2[1] = "space"`.

I don't understand why the 3rd and 4th `scanf` is scanning although the `printf` never got shown.

Comment: You shouldn't use spaces after %c in scanf()

Comment: omg my bad already removed them, problem is still there tho

Comment: Well, you have created an array of chars, and since strings do not exist in c, when you write "456" in your keyboard followed by enter, each of your 4 scanf's gets executed and store the chars 4, 5, 6 and enter respectively. The same happens with "2k"

Comment: So what can i do against it? or is it impossible

Comment: well if you want to scan "2k" in the first scanf, you need to create a 2d array like char card_T1[2][2]; or if you want to type "456" you have to create an array like this: char card_T1[2][3] . if you can use c++, just replace char with type string and leave the rest unchanged.

Comment: done it with %2a so only the first two mattered for the scanf. scanf("%2s",&card_T1);

Answer (score 0):

Try using %s instead of %c in the scanf statements(%c remains as it is in the printf statements). This will prevent the program to continue scanning card_T1[1] after you have pressed one character and enter afterwards. However you have to press one character at a time and enter afterwards. If you press '2k' and enter after(the first time you give input), only the character '2' will be stored in card_T1[0] and nothing will be stored in cardT1[1](of course also nothing in card_T2[0] or card_T2[1]). If you press '2', then enter, then 'k' and then enter, '2' will be stored in card_T1[0] and 'k' in card_T2[1]. Here is an example of what the program you run will look like after these changes(There is '1' before "Type in flop card 2:" because you forgot to put \n after printing card_T1[1] (Or because you didn't want to)):

```
Type in flop card 1: 
qwerty
123
q
1Type in flop card 2:
3
4
3
4
```

That is because each position in a char array is only 1 byte and each character also is 1 byte so only 1 character can fit a position of a char array. As for WHY %s instead of %d fixes the first problem I don't know either.